# Calls to Twilio Method is ambiguous

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

I am trying to send a SMS using twilio but when i use the code i get the following errors:

**Error 1**

> Error 11 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'Twilio.TwilioRestClient.SendMessage(string, string, string, string[], string)' 
>   and
>   'Twilio.TwilioRestClient.SendMessage(string, string, string, string[], System.Action)'
>   C:\Development\TestSMSVerify.aspx.cs

**Error 2**

```
Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

The code is

```
// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account 
string AccountSid = "MYSID";
string AuthToken = "MYAUTHTOKEN";
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
var message = twilio.SendMessage("+441618504425", "07914164512", "code is 123456", null, null);
Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
```

Comment: as `null` can be any reference type ,you need to explicitly cast the parameters which you want to pass

Comment: sorry i dont understand can you go into a bit more detail please

Comment: try this: `SendMessage("+441618504425", "07914164512", "code is 123456", new string[] { },String.Empty);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `SendMessage` has 2 overloads, one which takes a `string` type as the last parameter and one that takes an `Action<Twilio.Message>`. You are passing `null` for this which is acceptable for both of these types, however, confuses the compiler because it can't quite work out which method you want it to call.

For example, if you passed an empty string as the last parameter e.g.

```
 twilio.SendMessage("+441618504425", "07914164512", "code is 123456", null, "");
```

Then the compiler would know that you want the overload with the `string` parameter at the end, not the one with an `Action<Twilio.Message>`. Alternatively, if you passed an empty `Action<Twilio.Message>` parameter e.g.

```
 twilio.SendMessage("+441618504425", "07914164512", "code is 123456", null, (msg) => {});
```

Then it would know that you want the call which takes an `Action<Twilio.Message>` parameter and not a `string`.

Finally, I believe this error

> Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Is because `SendMessage` doesn't actually return anything. To fix, just change

```
var message = twilio.SendMessage(...);
```

To

```
twilio.SendMessage(...);
```